# Display of term reference in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have a field which has the following Field type and Widget.

```
FIELD TYPE      WIDGET
Term reference  Autocomplete term widget (tagging)
```

When I display the terms associated with this field, they appear with a hyperlink and dotted underline. Is there a way to display them as simple texts?

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the display format of the field from your content type's "Manage Display" settings tab to "Plain Text" instead of "Link". See the below screenshot:
[image]